# Link Prediction based Similarity Indices

Tags: predictive-modeling, social-network-analysis

So, I was reading some Link Prediction based algorithms and similarity indices. I came across two random walk based indices - Local Random Walk(LRW) and Superposed Random Walk(SRW). I read the standard and original papers on both, but couldn't understand them. Can someone please help me with understanding both of them properly?